# Saved image using PIL but image doesn't open

Tags: python, image, png, python-imaging-library

I want my python script so save the python window as a .JPG, which it does. But when I try and open that .jpg with any application it tells me the file type is unsupported.

When I save my file as a .eps file it opens correctly but when I try and save as any other file type the file will not open.

```py
win.postscript(file="image.jpg", colormode='color')

from PIL import Image as NewImage
img = NewImage.open("image.jpg")
```

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter canvas object can only be saved as a postscript file, which is actually a postscript printer language text file.

Thus if you call:

```
win.postscript(file="image.jpg", colormode='color')
```

*It will still write and create a postscript file*, that is why it works when you rename the extension [or simply append] with .ps

Check this blog for a better implementation: https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/code/216929/saving-a-tkinter-canvas-drawing-python